# Multi-module web project with Spring and Maven

Tags: java, project, web, spring, maven

Assume we have a few projects, *each* containing some web resources (e.g., html pages).

```
parent.pom
 +- web           (war)
 +- web-plugin-1  (jar)
 +- web-plugin-2  (jar)
 ...
```

Let's say `web` is the deployable `war` project which depends on the known, but selectable, set of plugins.

What is a good way to setup this using `Spring` and `maven`?

1. Let the plugins be `war` projects and use mavens **poor** support for importing other `war` projects
2. Put all web-resource for all plugins in the `web` project
3. Add all web-resources to the classpath of all `jar` `web-plugin-*` dependencie  and let spring read files from respective classpath?
4. Other?

I've previously come from using `#1`, but the `copy-paste` semantics of `war` dependencies in maven is horrible.

Answer (score 2):

well, i use to work with point 3, definining all dependencies at parent's pom, including dependencies form modules, like that:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>cat.base.baseframe</groupId>
    <artifactId>projecte-pare-baseframe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11.a</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>ogc.domini</module>
    <module>ogc.logica</module>
    <module>ogc.ejb</module>
    <module>ogc.ear</module>
    <module>ogc.ui</module>
    <module>ogc.assistent</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cat.base.cuesfeina</groupId>
        <artifactId>cuesfeina.domini</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cat.base.gea</groupId>
        <artifactId>gea.domini</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>baseOnline.ajudes</groupId>
        <artifactId>ajudes.domini</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cat.base.tramitador</groupId>
        <artifactId>tramitador.domini</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>cat.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>mme.domini</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

-->

everything at pom's parent's it's easy to find what you need. if you need to call some service i i use to create a public jar with functions to call the service like ejb...

Comment: Dear @ZaoTaoBao please have a sight at my question about creating java multi layer app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562268/create-java-multi-layer-application-using-maven-multi-module